# MvxSidebarPresentationAttribute is not configured in the presenter dictionary

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

> Unhandled Exception
>
> **System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException**:
>   The type MvxSidebarPresentationAttribute is not configured in the
>   presenter dictionary

- MvvmCros 5.6 Tools
- Visual studio 2015
- Windows 8.1
- iPhone 7 simulator iOS 10.3

**code**

Menu View

```
    [MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
    [MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Left, MvxPanelHintType.PushPanel, false)]
    public partial class MenuViewController : MvxViewController<MenuViewModel>
    {
        public MenuViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public MenuViewController() : base("MenuViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MenuViewController, MenuViewModel>();
            set.Bind(btnFirst).To(vm => vm.GotoFirstView);
            set.Bind(btnSecond).To(vm => vm.GotoSecondView);
            set.Apply();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
}
```

first View

```
[MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
[MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.ResetRoot, true)]
public partial class FirstViewController : MvxViewController<FirstViewModel>
{
    public FirstViewController() : base("FirstViewController", null)
    {
    }

    public FirstViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }
    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

second view

```
[MvxFromStoryboard("Main")]
    [MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.ResetRoot, true)]
    public partial class SecondViewController : MvxViewController<SecondViewModel>
    {
        public SecondViewController() : base("SecondViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public SecondViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
    }
```

i have used above code in my ios project but it just showing error in ouptut as

**Unhandled Exception**

**System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:** The type MvxSidebarPresentationAttribute is not configured in the presenter dictionary

Comment: Please provide more details and ideally a source code snippet for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `MvxSidebarPresenter` in the `Setup.cs` file of your iOS project:

```
protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
{
   return new MvxSidebarPresenter((MvxApplicationDelegate)ApplicationDelegate, Window);
}
```

You can see the working example [in the samples](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/8218d74b5d005929c047c9e026032323c389aacd/TestProjects/iOS-Support/XamarinSidebar/MvvmCross.iOS.Support.Sidebar/Setup.cs).

Comment: i have already added this override CreatePresenter Method and gone through sample you have provided but nothing is changed can you give any other demo or tutorial link for drawer in ios with mvvm cross.

Comment: You can use the project on the link I sent as a simple tutorial for the sidebar presenter - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/iOS-Support/XamarinSidebar

Comment: the demo project throws exception Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Now that is weird, I will check

Comment: i solved the exception by setting  `public virtual bool HasShadowing => false;` in **BaseMenuViewController**